# ASP.NET MVC 4 / SimpleMembership questions from a CakePHP guy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC (and .NET in general). I'm trying to throw together a basic website with some CRUD functionality, but I'm getting a little tripped up by EF and SimpleMembership. I've spent hours looking for good starter information, but it seems that MVC 4 is too new to have mature content (that I can understand).

Now for questions!

If I want to add a few models, like Jobs and Applications, should I lump them all together in a single, monolithic file or break each model into its own file?

How many DB contexts should I have? Would it look like this?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

Should the UsersContext (from SimpleMembership) remain separate from the context(s) I create for my models?

If I want to have multiple "navigation properties" (correct use?) from a Job to a User (e.g. a Poster and a Taker), do I do that like this?

```
public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public virtual User Poster { get; set; }
    public virtual User Taker { get; set; }
}
```

Related to the previous question, if I'm using SimpleMembership and separate the context(s) for my models and the UsersContext (as I presume I should, correct me if I'm wrong), how do I make references across context boundaries?

Answering these questions would really help me get off the ground! Thanks!

Comment: ASp.net MVc4 is pretty much the same as asp.net mvc 3 i.e 99% of mvc 3 is in mvc 4. In your place I'd forget about EF and predefined memberships because those are VERY OPTIONAL in the asp.net world. Yes they help you put up an app quite quick but that's it. Frankly I think that a micro-orm will be much easier for you to work with as it's closer to the php pdo way. EF or any other ORM are hard to learn if you're going beyond drag'n'drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each class should have it's own cs file with the name matching the name of the class:

Job.cs

Application.cs

MyContext.cs

You should have one DbContext for each database.  So if you want all these tables to be in the same database, then you need one DbContext.

Any references AFAIK across contexts would not have support.  You could add int foreign key properties, and create references with the attribute [NotMapped] and assign them manually when you grab the two entities separately from each database.  I.e.  `if(someJob.PosterKey == someUser.UserKey) { someJob.Poster = someUser }`.  Would be a bit of a pain though.

Edit: The first thing I'd probably do is take the UsersContext class out of the AccountsModel file and make it its own file.  Usually I name the context after my app.  So if my app was called Jobs Manager, I'd call the context JobsManagerContext and put it in the JobsManagerContext.cs file(I would also change the connection string to name my db JobsManager).  You could leave all the account model classes in the first file sense they are all generated together.  But create a new file for each one of your new model classes.